# When I deloy app nodejs to heroku I get issue

Tags: node.js, heroku

---

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! canvas@2.8.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.8.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

```
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.eYOj4/_logs/2021-07-23T14_32_47_369Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution ! The problem here is that "node-pre-gyp" can't be executed (code 126) You need to install it via : "npm i node-pre-gyp" Then you delete the node_modules folder from your local folder and the github repo and push your code. Then you build your main branch on herokuapp. It worked for me, I hope it will work for you.

Comment: ohh, thanks bro. I found the same solution. it work.